# Angular5 - Disable tag without hiding content

Tags: angular

So here is my problem:

I have a card with a form inside. The user can click on an "add" button that duplicates the card to have several times the same part of the form(up to 5 times).

I would like to change the card for expansion panels when there are several times the form. But I have no idea how to proceed.

I can only think about having my mat-expansion-panel tags and disable it when needed, but I dont want the content of the first one to be hided, as it has to come back to a simple card.

Also, having just one expansion panel when there is the form just once is no good, it really needs to go back to a card.

Here is a sample of code to illustrate it:

```
<form fxFill [formGroup]="newRequest" novalidate>
  <div *ngFor="let item of newRequest.controls['roundway']; let i=index">
    <mat-card fxfill>
     ***several mat-form-field***
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</form>
```

So the idea is that when roundway.length==1, I have a mat-card tag as in the example code above, and when roundway.length>1, I get something like this:

```
<form fxFill [formGroup]="newRequest" novalidate>
      <mat-accordion>
        <div *ngFor="let item of newRequest.controls['roundway']; let i=index">
          <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                Title {{i}}
              </mat-panel-title>
              <mat-panel-description>
                Description {{i}}
              </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            ***several mat-form-field***
         </mat-expansion-panel>
       </div>
     <mat-accordion>
   </form>
```

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answer? I mean my html tags are supposed to change depending on a variable...

Comment: Oops sorry this was stupid of me. So I cannot really put my code as I only have my regular mat-card yet, it would not help to add the code, so I put a sample illustrating what I would like to get.
I really have absolutely no idea of how to do this without putting both with a ngIf, but this would repeat my mat-form-fields.